# VB.Net Email not putting copy in sent folder

Tags: vb.net, email

I'm going mad here!

Sending emails in VB.Net is working fine, even the read/delivery receipts are working. What it's *not* doing, is putting a copy of the email it sends in the sent folder. Is there something else I need to do as I've searched high a low for a solution but can't see anything.

```
                        EMail.From = New MailAddress(sSENDERaddress)
                        EMail.Body = sMessage
                        EMail.Subject = sSubject

                        If sAttached <> "" Then
                            Dim mAttachment As New Attachment(sAttached)
                            EMail.Attachments.Add(mAttachment)
                        End If
                        EMail.Headers.Add("Return-Receip-To", sSENDERaddress)
                        EMail.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", sSENDERaddress)
                        EMail.Headers.Add("Return-Path", sSENDERaddress)
                        EMail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure Or DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess ' this will send an email to the SENDER'S email address confirming that the original email was sent. If the sender doesn't get the email, then it didn't go. Simples
                        SMTPServer.Host = GetMailServerAddress()
                        SMTPServer.Port = GetMailPort()
                        SMTPServer.Credentials = Authentication 
                        Try
                            SMTPServer.Send(EMail)
                            'EMail.Dispose()
                            bRET = True
                        Catch ex As Exception
                            ''debug.Print(ex.Message)
                            ExceptIt(ex.Message)
                            'EMail.Dispose()
                            bRET = False
                        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a few more posts on this subject, and it looks like you can't do it. The only Heath Robinson solution is to add a BCC to my sending address...

UPDATE: For those interested, it's not an SMTP function, but an IMAP one. I suppose, if you want to, you can spend hours working the code out for this, but I found this

https://www.example-code.com/vbnet/sendWithCopyToSentMailbox.asp

Where you simply append to the sent items...

```
'  Now use Chilkat IMAP to save the email to Inbox.Sent

Dim imap As New Chilkat.Imap

'  Connect to an IMAP server.
'  Use TLS
imap.Ssl = True
imap.Port = 993
success = imap.Connect("mail.mydomain.com")
If (success <> True) Then
    Console.WriteLine(imap.LastErrorText)
    Exit Sub
End If


'  Login
success = imap.Login("myLogin","myPassword")
If (success <> True) Then
    Console.WriteLine(imap.LastErrorText)
    Exit Sub
End If


'  The AppendMail method uploads an email to an IMAP server
'  and saves it in the mailbox specified:
success = imap.AppendMail("Inbox.Sent",email)
If (success <> True) Then
    Console.WriteLine(imap.LastErrorText)
    Exit Sub
End If


Console.WriteLine("Mail saved to Inbox.Sent")
```